# pyspark create all possible combinations of column values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I want to get all the possible combinations of size 2 of a column in pyspark dataframe.
My pyspark dataframe looks like

```
| id |
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |

For above input, I want to get output as 

| id1 |  id2 |
|  1  |   2  |
|  1  |   3  |
|  1  |   4  |
|  2  |   3  |
and so on..
```

One way would be to collect the values and get them into python iterable (list, pandas df) and use `itertools.combinations` to generate all combinations.

```
values = df.select(F.collect_list('id')).first()[0]
combns = list(itertools.combinations(values, 2))
```

However, I want to avoid collecting the dataframe column to the driver since the rows can be extremely large. Is there a better way to achieve this using spark APIs?

Comment: what about crossjoin? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `crossJoin` method, and then cull the lines with `id1 > id2`.

```
df = df.toDF('id1').crossJoin(df.toDF('id2')).filter('id1 < id2')
```